# Crystal Reports - Adding to the Data Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, datasource

whenever I add one field to a Crystal Report I'm working on, whenever I try to launch the report I get this heinous error message from our web interface:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Database logon failed.
at Accellos.Platform.CommunicationService.ExternalReports.ExportReport(String productId, 
ExternalReportsServerInstance serverInstance, String xmlReportDataSource, 
ExternalReportExportFormatType exportFormat)
```

Maybe I'm just not doing it right. I went into **Database > Database Expert", added a datasource location, added the table from the database I needed, linked it to the other tables that were already in the report, added the field I needed to the report, then saved it.

I am by no means an Expert in Crystal Reports. In fact, I've never touched anything in Crystal Reports before. Have I done this wrong? It seemed like it was very straight forward.

Comment: Sadly, nothing in Crystal reports is straight forward.  This error has 'logon failed' pretty easy to spot...did you specify proper credentials to get to the new data source?  Is it a file, or ODBC/JDBC connection, or .... ?

Comment: Yes, I see that it says login failed, but I did not change the credentials. The login is the same for both databases, I checked and double checked that. I think this has something to do with the script that runs to produce the reports.

Comment: If the login credentials are incorrect, you wouldn't have even seen the table from the database to add it to your report.  Not sure how to help here without suggesting alternatives...do you (or maybe your dba?) know how to handle linked servers?  Keep crystal reports as having the one data source/connection and use linked servers on that one machine to call the other tables you need from other servers (I've had success with that setup in the past, but I've never seen the error you have here).

Comment: After a bit more research, and consulting with my fellow IT folk as well as our software vendor, it seems this is not a Crystal Reports problem. This is a problem with our WMS, so I'm going to just have to devise a work around on that end.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, folks, this wasn't so much a Crystal Reports problem as it was an Accellos problem.

I wish I had more to contribute on this, but we're just going to mirror the data in the Accellos database and add some SQL to the stored procedure that keeps that database consistent with our SAP database.